# Google Chrome. Подключение не защищено

Tags: google-chrome

Добрый день. Есть VB c локальным хостингом, сегодня при обращении хром начал выдавать "Подключение не защищено". FF открывает без проблем. Кто-нибудь знает, куда копать?

Comment: Вероятно, там нет https или сертификат не считается хромом надежным.

Comment: Странно, сегодня такое началось. Остальные браузеры нормально открывают